# How to set Application Item value in a Page Item

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a application Item in which I have fetched the value of user logged in.

How to fetch that value in page item

Answer (score 0):

You mean, how to put application item's value into a page item?

```
:P1_USER := :APPLICATION_ITEM;
```

(I don't know which names you really use, but that's pretty much straightforward).

---

On the other hand, **why** did you create an application item for that? What's wrong with `:APP_USER` which is already built-in?

Comment: already done but not working :P5_SET_EMP := :APP_ID;

Comment: APP_ID represents application ID, not user who is connected to your application.